How to avoid null Values in a .NET 6+ ASP.NET project
I'm currently exploring multiple options to get rid of null values in my .net web api applications.
Let's say, that we have the following Project:
#nullable disable

public record Todo(Guid Id, string Description, bool IsDone);

public interface ITodoRepository
{
    Todo Get(Guid id);
}

[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class TodoController : ControllerBase
{
    private ITodoRepository _todoRepository;

    public TodoController(ITodoRepository todoRepository)
    {
        _todoRepository = todoRepository;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Get(Guid id)
    {
        var todoItem = _todoRepository.Get(id);
        if (todoItem is null) return NotFound();

        return Ok(todoItem);
    }
}

Disclaimer: The nullable reference types feature is explicitly deactivated to show the transformation from an old poject.
My questsions are:

Which of the following approaces would you prefere and why?
Which of the following approaces wouldn't use and why?
Do you see any other options to avoid null values?
Do you know good rescources (books, articles, talks, videos, ...) about this topic?

Nullable
By activating the nullable reference types feature all possible null values are explicitly marked and checked by the compiler.
#nullable enable

public record Todo(Guid Id, string Description, bool IsDone);

public interface ITodoRepository
{
    Todo? Get(Guid id);
}

[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class TodoController : ControllerBase
{
    private ITodoRepository _todoRepository;

    public TodoController(ITodoRepository todoRepository)
    {
        _todoRepository = todoRepository;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Get(Guid id)
    {
        var todoItem = _todoRepository.Get(id);
        if (todoItem is null) return NotFound();

        return Ok(todoItem);
    }
}

I think this is a big improvement because i can't forget to check if i get a null value from the repository. The downside is that i didn't removed the null value.
Maybe
This example uses the nullable reference types feature and maybes as return types instead of nullable types. I think this is a little bit more expressive and restrictive than only using a nullable types.
#nullable enable

public record Todo(Guid Id, string Description, bool IsDone);

public interface ITodoRepository
{
    Maybe<Todo> Get(Guid id);
}

[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class TodoController : ControllerBase
{
    private ITodoRepository _todoRepository;

    public TodoController(ITodoRepository todoRepository)
    {
        _todoRepository = todoRepository;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Get(Guid id)
    {
        var todoItem = _todoRepository.Get(id);
        if (todoItem.HasNoValue) return NotFound();

        return Ok(todoItem.Value);
    }
}

I personally don't like to use it because i often use the Result type from CSharpFunctionalExtensions the combination of both patterns would lead to constructs like
public interface ISomethingCommandHandler
{
    Maybe<Result<Todo, Error>> DoSomething(DoSomethingCommand command);
}

Exception
This example uses the nullable reference types feature and the "Application logic" throws a custom Exception if an item isn't found in the database. The custom Exception is catched by a custom middleware that logs and transforms the exception into a 404 NotFound response.
#nullable enable

public record Todo(Guid Id, string Description, bool IsDone);

public interface ITodoRepository
{
    Todo? Get(Guid id);
}

public class GetTodoByIdQueryHandler
{
    private ITodoRepository _todoRepository;

    public GetTodoByIdQueryHandler(ITodoRepository todoRepository){
      _todoRepository = todoRepository;
    }

    public Todo Handle(GetTodoByIdQuery query){
      var todo = _todoRepository.Get(query.Id);
      if(todo is null) throw new ItemNotFoundException();

      return todo;
    }
}

public sealed class NotFoundMiddleware
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public NotFoundMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, ILogger logger)
    {
        _next = next;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            await _next.Invoke(context);
        }
        catch (ItemNotFoundException e)
        {
            _logger.LogWarning(e, "ItemNotFound: ");
            
            context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.NotFound;

            if (e.UserErrorMessage is not null)
            {
                await context.Response.WriteAsync(e.UserErrorMessage);
            }

            await context.Response.CompleteAsync();
        }
    }
}

[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class TodoController : ControllerBase
{
    private GetTodoByIdQueryHandler _queryHandler;

    public TodoController(GetTodoByIdQueryHandler queryHandler)
    {
        _queryHandler = queryHandler;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Get(Guid id)
    {
        return Ok(_queryHandler.Handle(new GetTodoByIdQuery(id)));
    }
}

personal pros:

the controllers dont have to deal with null types
after the "application logic" has checked the null value there are no more null values

personal cons:

application flow is controlled by exceptions
if something isn't found in the database the exception + stacktrace is logged --> in the logfile it looks like something went wrong
null value handling is hidden
you have to know which method throws this exception and maybe rethrow it when catching other exceptions
you have to know when to throw this exception an when not

for me there is a difference between an expected "NotFound error" (for example a wrong url) and an unexpected "NotFound error" (a bug in the application)




FYI support for .NET 6 ends in November: https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/platform/support/policy/dotnet-core . Why not upgrade the project to .NET 8?

check out ProblemDetails link

You're asking a debatable question as all approaches are valid and commonly used. It's a matter of which approach that you see is more suitable to your current codebase. Your goal should be to implement the code while reserving  the existing coding experience to keep the overall code in harmony.
There are many libraries that helps with functional programing, however, not all of them should be used every time and everywhere. In general you should set a roadmap on which feature should/not be used in your project. This way, you will have more control on the flow control, and even control the dependencies if any.
throwing exceptions in the other hand, is very expensive operation in .NET. You should not treat a normal flow as an exceptional error flow, like validating user inputs. Instead, use a return-value for normal flow where expected to be handled, and catch the unhandled exceptions that might be thrown where cannot be controlled, like third-party exceptions, services exceptions ..etc.
You can however, use exception as an argument validation in contractors where you want the code flow to break if the requirements are not met. This is useful when you implement a code that would be reused, and you want to enforce its requirements like using exceptions at your domain layer as a guard to force other layers to use the domain requirements, or developing a NuGet package. Only use exceptions where you see it's a appropriate.
That's being said, in your API, you might be better using a result return value. Validate arguments, and return the results. You can use your middleware to catch any exception thrown, where you only return a 500 status code, with a generic message to the client, and log that exception details to your advantage. This will hide the details from the client, but you will find the details in the logs. You can also use Problem and ProblemDetails objects to define a very detailed response to the client using RFC 9457 specification Read More....
You can define your generic client errors (e.g. Not Found), and just reuse them across all your controllers.
You can use Result object, and extend it to have a Match method, where you pass the value, and return the value if Success or return error if Failure.
There are many solutions and different ways to handle that, but as I mentioned in above, it depends on which your code favor most.
It's also good to have a unified structure between all your endpoints so the client response experience would be seamless. (I've worked on many APIs, and I favored APIs with a result response structure where I can model the result in my code and just reuse that as a container with all other endpoints).
